# cannot access server terminal in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, ssh

i am new to Ubuntu OS. I recently installed Ubuntu Server 14.04. in addition to that i also checked the option of installing ubuntu desktop so it installed ubuntu 14.04 lts with that. 
Now when the system loads up it takes me directly to Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS. 
Okay here's what i want to do. i want to access the server using our client machine that is why i installed desktop(client) along with the server. But as i get into login screen of desktop i have no option to access the Server terminal.
Please I need help...

Comment: Is openssh-server (or any other ssh-server like dropbear) installed on the server?

Comment: Also you might want to make your question a little more clear what you want to achieve and how your setup looks like.

Comment: A full desktop does not really help much and clearly you are not wanting graphical access. I agree with the suggestion for ssh. If you want graphical management use the web based tools such as webmin, they are designed with server tasks in mind (unlike Unity).

Comment: Are you trying to run the server and client on the same machine? It's not really clear what your environment is nor what you are trying to achieve exactly. Please [edit] your question to provide information that will help us help you. It may be helpful to review: http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Install SSH server daemon on `server` machine:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo service ssh start
```

Configuration files are in `/etc/ssh/`

Create user for server (do not use root or your own account if possible)

```
mkdir /home/jimmy
sudo useradd jimmy -s /bin/sh -d /home/jimmy
sudo chown jimmy /home/jimmy
```

And enter password for new `jimmy` user.

For `clients`

Access from another machine:

```
ssh jimmy@hostname

ssh jimmy@ip_addr
```

Port 22 (TCP) must be open. It's recommended to change port number and do not use password login if machine is available from public net.

Comment: use this command in client (ubuntu Desktop)?

Comment: apoorv@dell-latitude:~$ sudo useradd server -s /bin/sh -d /home/server
sudo: unable to resolve host dell-latitude

Comment: SSH server must be installed on machine considered `server`, and user must be added on it. Using `ssh` command is for any `client` machines. User on server machine is used to execute commands on server, client logins by this user name and his password.

Comment: @ApoorvKumar it's totally unclear what are you trying to achieve and what do you get instead.